# C# DataSetの使い道を教えてください。

Tags: c#, database

お世話になります。

初歩な質問でいつもすみません。
C#を使用し、Accessとデータのやり取りを行う必要がでてきたので
勉強から始め直したのですが、このDataSetの使い道がいまだによくわかりません。

まず、『メモリ上にデータを保持する』とか書いてあるのですが、これは単に
ListやDictionary等のコレクションクラスで二次元などの配列を作り、
そこに値を入れていくということとはまた別なのでしょうか？
もし同じなら、わざわざDataSetなるもを使用せずとも、自分で領域を作ってさえおけば
それで用が事足りてしまうのではないかという気がします。

また、DataSet側の値を操作、変更してもデータベース側も自動で変更されるわけでは
ないので、結局はADOなどでゴリゴリSQLを走らせなければならないというと、
『ただの入れ物』にすぎないということなのでしょうか？

やりたいことは、データベース側のデータをリアルタイムで取得し、変更などが
行われた場合にデータベース側への更新を極力少ない手間で行いたいのですが、
そういったことはこのDataSetは受け付けてくれるのでしょうか？

基本的な内容で申し訳ありませんが、何卒お願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2001年当時のADO.NET関連の機能や概念のために作られていまし「た」。
・型付きDataSet, 型なしDataSet（join Select、DataTableのグループ化など）
・型付きDataTable, 型なしDataTable（DBのテーブルに対応）
・TableAdapter（単純なDBのテーブルへのCRUD操作の対応）
・データバインディング

これは主に2つの視点から見ることができます。

1. 2001年当時の、現在でいうORM自動生成機能（結局SQL直書きがmustなので流行らず※）
2. DataGridViewなどWindows.Forms UIパーツとの双方向データバインド。MVVMのVM的

2番はDataGridViewなどでバインドが非常に便利なので、今でもよく使われます。
（EntityFrameworkやDapperで取得した内容を、わざわざDataTableに詰めなおす、などやったり…）

普通のコレクションもバインドはできますが、UI側が強制的にReadonlyになります。
・List型
・配列 etc.

※
単純なSelect/Insert/Update/Deleteであれば、
TableAdapterのメソッド呼び出しでSQL自動発行されるのですが、
実業務でそんな単純に済むことが多くなく、結局SQL書いた方が早くね？ってなります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。結果的に、『使える』ものですか？UIに表示する必要がなく、内部で変数のように使用するだけなら、わざわざ使う必要もない代物ですか？

Comment: 「内部で変数のように」使用するだけなら、必要はありません。DataGridViewやそれに類するUIパーツとバインドしたいかどうかで判断すればよいかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございました。結果、『必要なし』と判断させていただきました^^